# static const cached result

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants

In the following example -

```
#include <iostream>

int someMethod(){
  static int a = 20;
  static const int result = a + 1;
  ++a;
  std::cout << " [" << a << "] ";
  return result;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << someMethod() << "\n";
  std::cout << someMethod() << "\n";
  std::cout << someMethod() << "\n";
}
```

The output comes as -

> [21] 21
>
> [22] 21
>
> [23] 21

What is the reason that is preventing `result` value to be modified on subsequent calls made to the same function? I've printed the output of variable `a` as well, which is certainly being incremented and since it is static as well there must not be multiple copies existing for the same method.

[**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/Fc5Ue4) - [**COMPILER OUTPUT**](https://godbolt.org/g/jZl82B)

Comment: The reason being that it is `static const`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const` here only disturb the reader from the real cause. This code performs exactly the same.

```
int someMethod(){
  static int a = 20;
  static int result = a + 1;
  ++a;
  std::cout << " [" << a << "] ";
  return result;
}
```

The real reason is that the `=` sign can represent two different operations in C++: an assignation (executed each time) or an initialisation (executed only when the variable is created). The difference in when it is part of *declaration/definition* of the variable.

In normal context (not bloc static variables), both are equivalent because an automatic variable is created every time the block in which it is declared it run (or at least the compiler must ensure that all behaves *as if* it that the case).

But for a block static variable the initialization occurs only once and here the variable result is initialized to 21 and its value will never change.

Those variants would be much different

```
int someMethod(){
  static int a = 20;
  static int result;
  result = a + 1; // assignation: result will see its value change with the value of a
  ...

int someMethod(){
  static int a = 20;
  static const int result = a;
  result = a + 1;  // Error modification of a const declared variable
```

Comment: A good answer, but in the last two lines in the last code block are two little errors. 

'static const int result' has to be initialised as it is const and modifiing 'result' in the following line will also end up in a compiler error not in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Since `result` is static, it will be initialized only once during runtime.Therefore the following line is executed only once no matter how many times you call `someMethod()`

```
 static const int result = a + 1;
```

Comment: @George Yes, i meant initialize.static variable is initialized only once.Right?

Comment: @George. Can you please explain why.

Comment: @George Eh? Initialization of a function local static only happens the first time control flows over the declaration. So why would the initializer be evaluated over and over?

Comment: @George It isn't. Please delete your comments to reduce the confusion here.

Answer (score 1):

Static is a hint to the compiler not to reinitialize a variable aside from forcing the compiler to allocate the variable's value on the program's data segment.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by others, `result` is a `static` variable so it's initialized only at the first execution of `someMethod()`.

And `result` is also `const`, so the first value assigned with

```
static const int result = a + 1;
```

remain unmodified for the following execution of the program.

I suppose you were expecting something that is achievable using a **reference**; if you modify the preceding line as follows

```
static const int & result = a;
                 ^
// note the & ---|
```

you link `result` to `a` and modifying `a` you modify `result` and the output is

```
[21] 21
[22] 22
[23] 23
```

The problem is that you can reference a variable to another variable, not to an expression; so you can link `result` to `a`, not to `a+1` (not to the dynamic value of `a+1`); so the following line

```
static const int & result = a + 1;
```

compile but (if I'm not wrong) link `result` to the unnamed variable where is stored (at the first execution of `someMethod()`) the result of the expression `a + 1`, so the output is again

```
 [21] 21
 [22] 21
 [23] 21
```

Comment: I think the `a + 1` version is legal (but of course refers to a fixed value as you say)

Comment: @M.M - sorry but... `a` is `static` too, so why the reference will dangle on subsequent calls to the function?

Comment: You're right, I was imagining a version where `a` was a function parameter for some reason